# Where in the story do the non story missions fit?

Tags: zombies-run

In *Zombies, Run* there are several modes in addition to the normal story. Namely these are:

- Airdrop
- Supply
- Race

How do these fit in the story (or does it even matter)?

I read that [Airdrop](http://blog.zombiesrungame.com/post/64870226869/introducing-airdrop-mode) missions should be played during the first half of season two and [race](http://zombiesrun.wikia.com/wiki/Race_Missions) missions between missions 13 and 14 of season one. Does this mean all race missions in ascending order (even the second set)? What about the other types?

Is there some kind of overview including all missions? Or will the missions just occur on the main (home) screen where the I can select the next normal mission?

Answer (score 1):

The [official Zombies, Run web blog](http://blog.zombiesrungame.com/post/82781977662/the-story-so-far) states that the race missions for Abel and New Canton take place chronologically "just before the finale" of season one, though I've seen [multiple sites](https://o0yono0o.tumblr.com/post/160331071010/zombies-run-chronological-mission-order) saying the chronological order places them between Patient 29 and Virtuous Circle. And now that training missions and Zombies, Run! 5K have been released, you may want to run those *before* Season One.

As each Race mission in order seems to contain references to the next race mission, I would suggest running them in order (if you have the endurance or desire to run them). If you don't, you can read the [transcripts on the Wiki](https://zombiesrun.wikia.com/wiki/5k_Ultra-Violet#Transcript) or turn off the GPS and just listen to them, as though another runner assumed your number in your place. Canon is what we make of it, after all. Each set of race missions is meant to be run in ascending order, with the second set immediately following the first.

Supposedly, the Supply missions are interspersed throughout Season One and the Airdrop missions are peppered throughout Season Two [as shown on this post](https://o0yono0o.tumblr.com/post/160331071010/zombies-run-chronological-mission-order). There doesn't seem to be any sort of in-app overview listing all the missions. On my app's mission page they are split by category, with Story missions being shown separately from Airdrop, Race, and Supply missions. The 'next mission' feature only cycles through the Story missions, and only if you have them downloaded. Otherwise, the app will switch to Radio mode.